# Accidentally removed the Gnome packages, how to re-install those using wget command from tty screen, unable to use install gnome commands?

Tags: package-management, gnome-shell, gui, tty

As the Gnome packages was removed accidentally, how can we reinstall those using the wget command, I've tried updating & upgrading the system (Ubuntu 22.10), the dist-upgrade command I can't use as due to use of it, I may lose the system data. Can anyone suggest me how can I install the Gnome desktop as I'm stuck in the tty screen, re-installing of Gnome packages shows that the no installation candidate for any of the commands for the Gnome package installation ?

Comment: You've not mentioned what GNOME packages were erased, nor what OS/release you're using, but why not just use `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` which is what I'd use to re-install all GNOME Shell, packages & GNOME software (*as provided on a Ubuntu Desktop system*). I'd not expect any loss of my files by doing that (*I re-installed this box on 29 August 2023 and lost **no** files via re-install from booted media; which is more than what I'm suggesting here*)

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/07/27/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2023/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Stull unable to reinstall the ubuntu desktop using the above command, as you've suggested @guiverc, Is it possible if we can get the gnome desktop packages, If it's possible to download it from any other 3rd party sources/repository ?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 is EOL as stated; which means repositories are either *dropped* (for mirrors & 3rd party) or *moved* (for the main archive as per the EOLUpgrades link I provided). We (*this Ubuntu community site*) haven't supported Ubuntu 22.10 since it reached EOL or *End of Life*.  All details are in the EOLUpgrades link I provided; though with one 22.10 systems I had here when EOL was reached; I just non-destructively re-install Ubuntu 23.10 on it & it became my 23.10 support box (*I already had a 23.04 box thus why I didn't release-upgrade normally*)